# How to construct inverse of elements in $C(K)/M_p$.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a topological space. $C(K)=\{f:K\to \mathbb R| \text{f is continuous}\}$

and for some $p\in K$ $$M_p=\{f\in C(K)| f(p)=0\}$$

I know this question was asked a lot but I am so confused and I need some clearifications.

1. For $M_p$ to be an ideal $K$ must be compact? To define multiplication is closed?
2. To show $M_p$ is maximal we can use $\phi:C(K)\to \mathbb R$ defined as $\phi(f)=f(p)$ which is surjective and ring homomorphism whose kernel is $M_p$ then by first isomorphism theorem, $C(K)/M_p\cong \mathbb R$ which is field iff $M_p$ is maximal.

2 is okay but I want to construct inverse functions in $C(K)/M_p$.

Let us now assume $K$ is compact Hausdorff take $f+M_p \in C(K)/M_p$

I know that we just cannot take $1/f+M_p$ because $1/f$ not necessery continuous.

E.g. $f=x^2-x$, $K=[0,1]$ and $p=1/2$ then $f\not\in M_p$ but $1/f\not\in C(K)$

Any hint to create inverses in $C(K)/M_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ has inverse if and only if $f(p)\neq 0$ so if and only if the constant function $f(p)\not \in M_p$. Observe that

$f=(f-f(p))+f(p)$ and $f-f(p)\in M_p$.

Then $1/f(p) f=1/f(p)(f-f(p))+1$ so the inverse of $f$ in $C(K)/M_p$ is the constant function $1/f(p)$.

Comment: So representations of functions in the quotients are only constant ones.

Comment: also for 1., for $M_p$ to be an ideal do we need $K$ being compact?

Comment: No, for 1. you don't need any additional assumption. Compactness is needed to conclude that **all** maximal ideals of $C(K)$ are of the form $M_p$ for some $p \in K$.

Comment: @MichealBrainHurts yes exactly